# jQuery, which is best, assigning element to variable or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

While reading jQuery and Bootstrap documentation I often see this:

```
var modal = $('#someid');
modal.find('.something').text('something');
modal.find('.somethingelse').text('somethingelse');
```

It first assigns the element to a variable, then works from there. However I usually write this:

```
$('#someid').find('.something').text('something');
$('#someid').find('.somethingelse').text('somethingelse');
```

My question is, are there reasons for using the first method - assigning to a variable - other than the syntax itself? Is it faster or better regarding the DOM?

Comment: @Maidul not really a dupe

Comment: So storing it in a variable you look up the element once. Not using it, you look up the element twice. What do you think is more efficient. Using something you have already a reference to or having to search the DOM all over again to find the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method is preferred for multiple reasons.

- It cuts down on the number of times the DOM has to be accessed, which is a relatively slow operation and so it performs better.
- It reduces the number of times your code instantiates a new jQuery object from an existing Element object, which is another performance benefit.
- It [DRYs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) up the code so that the same statements are not needlessly repeated.

As such you should always follow this practice, known colloquially as 'caching the selector', where possible.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I had a feeling that this was the case.